# YouTube Live Stream RTMP URL

Tags: youtube, jwplayer, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have live event on YouTube and I'd like to broadcast it on my website. I want to make my event private, grab it's RTMP broadcasting URL and paste it on my website, in JWPlayer.

Is that possible?

Providing YouTube live URL to JWPlayer is not working. Already tried.

Comment: YouTube has an RTMP URL? Also it is possible to do YouTube Live, but with a bit of a hack. I will answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for YouTube live with JW Player 6.12. Keep in mind the YouTube URL needs to be actually broadcasting for this to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Live YouTube</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        file: "//www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3dnUonOGOs",
        primary: 'flash'
    });
    jwplayer().onPlay(function () {
      VideoLength = jwplayer().getDuration() * 1000;
      jwplayer().seek(jwplayer().getDuration());
      jwplayer().getPosition() * 1000;
    });
    jwplayer().onPause(function () {
      jwplayer().getPosition() * 1000;
    });
    jwplayer().onBuffer(function () {
      jwplayer().getPosition() * 1000;
    });
    jwplayer().onComplete(function () {
      jwplayer().getPosition() * 1000;
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, remove the primary flash line.

Comment: It worked, but it player acts live it is streaming a video on demand, is it possible to make player say that this is live streaming and make seek controls disabled? see attached
http://i.imgur.com/TDddANe.png

Comment: Yes, my API events on the page should have updated the seek bar to make it look like it is live DVR. Or you can make a custom skin with controls missing. Or set the controls variable to false.

Comment: Thanks for instructions

Comment: No problem, any time.

Comment: I think this is more a solution and less of a real answer to the question. I too need to know how to get the RTMP with the YouTube Live API, there doesn't seem to be documentation on how to do that anywhere. :-(

Comment: That is really a question about YouTube's API itself, not related to the JW Player. I wasn't aware that the YouTube API even provided an RTMP url, as RTMP's popularity has been fading, especially with new streaming formats on the horizon (HLS, DASH.etc) . . .

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/streaming-sites.435/#post-2448. rtmp: //a.rtmp.youtube.com/videolive?sparams=id%2Citag%2Cns%2Cexpire&itag=34&ipbits=0&expire=xxx&key=yt_qc&signature=xxx&ns=yt-live&id=xxx